# Rational equivalence and ''$\mathbb{A}^1$-equivalence" for zero cycles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-cycles

Let $k$ be a field, let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^r$ be a smooth projective algebraic variety defined over $k$.

We define an equivalence relation on the group of zero cycles $Z_0(X)$ in the following way:

> For  $A_1,A_2\in Z_0(X)$ of degree $n$, we define them to be $\mathbb{A}^1$-equivalent, if there exists a degree $m$ cycle $B\in Z_0(X)$ , such that $A_1+B$ and $A_2+B$ are effecitve, corresponding to points $x_1,x_2\in \mathrm{Sym}^{n+m}(X)$, and there exists a morphism $f\colon\mathbb{P}^1\to\mathrm{Sym}^{n+m}(X)$, such that $f(0)=x_1,f(\infty)=x_2$. Mumford defined the "rational equivalence" to be the equivalence relation on $Z_0(X)$ generated by the $\mathbb{A}^1$-equivalence, see [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250523940).

I am not sure if Mumford's rational equivalence coincides with the standard one defined by Fulton... More precisely, I am not sure about the following questions:

(0) By the result [here](https://people.kth.se/~dary/thesis/thesis-paperIII.pdf), there is a map $$\mathrm{Sym}^s(X)\to\mathrm{Chow}_{0,s}(X\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^r)$$ which is only known to be homeomorphism in char $0$. But in general, conversely, given a zero cycle, how does one assign a $k$-point in the symmetric product?

(1) Over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, does this notation coincide with the usual notion of rational equivalence?

(2) Over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$, do the notions coincide?

(3) Over an non-algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, do the two notions coincide?

(4) In case (2),(3) are false, does Mumford's theorem: "$H^{2,0}(S)>0$ implies $\mathrm{CH}_0(S)$ is not finitely generated" still hold in those cases?

Comment: Your definition of "$\Bbb{A}^1$-equivalent" does not appear in Mumford's paper. It is not equivalent to rational equivalence, even over $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: @abx Thanks for comment, yes, sorry I gave it a wrong name, but I think such definition for surfaces over $\mathbb{C}$ appeared on Mumford's "Rational equivalence of 0-cycles on surfaces" [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250523940)? Also is there a concrete example where this notion is shown not equivalent to the usual rational equivalence? Thanks!

Comment: No, Mumford gives the usual definition. Yes, there are many examples: take for instance a surface $S$ with a degree 2 map $S\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$, branched along a curve of degree $\geq 6$. Let $C\subset S$ be the ramification locus; it is easy to see that two general points of $C$ are rationally equivalent, but there are no rational curves passing through them.

Comment: @abx Sorry I oversimplified the definition...I re-edited the question: let's allow the rational equivalence after adding some effective cycles, and allow the equivalence generated by $\mathbb{A}^1$-equivalences, namely, connected by a chain of rational curves. Does this notion coincides with the usual notion of rational equivalence (by Fulton)? I feel the definition using symmetric product is weird, as it does not represent families of zero cycles.

Comment: @abx, And sorry I didn't quite get the point... why are those two points in the ramification locus rationally equivalent?

Comment: Call your 2 points $p$ and $q$, then $2(p-q)$ is zero in $CH_0(S)$, which is torsion free. Alternatively, take an Enriques surface: any 2 points are rationally equivalent, but $S$ is not covered by rational curves.

Comment: ... and your new definition is indeed that of Mumford.

Comment: @abx Yes, and the question I feel confused is: Why does Mumford's notion coincide with Fulton's, or it doesn't?

Comment: It does, though this is not obvious. Start with the (easy) case of a cycle linearly equivalent to zero on an irreducible curve, then extend to the case the curve is reducible.